# Sarg on Endian firewall

Tags: linux, unix, firewall, bandwidth

I am running endian firewall release 2.2.rc3 and I have just installed sarg to monitor bandwidth usage but I sarg daily index.html is not being created. Has anyone come across such scenarios?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

append the access.log file in sarg.conf to access_short

Answer (score 0):

You could also look at [SRG](http://crc.net.nz/software/srg.php), written when SARG stopped being maintained a few years ago.

Comment: Endian firewall wont install pacakages easily, its a linux distro modified to suite the packages shipped with endian

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check the permissions for the squid logs, then the permissions for the output directory and finally if your web publishing directory is available.

Double check the sarg.conf file and look if you are using the correct paths.

HTH

Comment: Permissions are fine, I think one of the problem is the date, its using the date 1Jan1970...this now annoying me big time! I have uninstalled it deleted all the files associated with it, reinstalled again nothing seem to be working!

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed anything in endian's output log format? SARG will parse default log format only. 
That could explain why it doesn't show correct time...

Was using SARG with Squid, everything was fine until I changed Squid log format to something readable. And found that it should not even *look like* default, it has to *be* default.